Definitions of complex analytic spaces
I have come across two different definitions of complex analytic spaces.
One is from the nlab:

A complex analytic test space is a common vanishing locus of a set of holomorphic functions $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$. This is naturally a locally ringed space over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. A complex analytic space is a locally ringed space over $\mathbb{C}$ that is locally isomorphic to such a complex analytic test space.

The other is from one of Serre's papers:

If $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, we say that $U$ is analytic if, for each $x \in U$, there are functions $f_1,...f_k$, holomorphic in a neighborhood $W$ of $x$, such that $U\cap W$ is identical to the set of points $x \in W$ satisfying the equations $f_i(z) = 0, i=1,...,k$. We call an analytic space a set $X$ equipped with a topology and a sheaf $\mathcal{O}$, such that there exists an open cover $\{V_i\}$ of $X$ such that each $V_i$ equipped with the topology and sheaf induced by those of $X$, is isomorphic to an analytic subset $U_i$ of an affine space and the topology of $X$ is Hausdorff.

I wonder whether these two definitions are different from each other. I think the biggest distinction is that the first one is locally isomorphic to zero locus of some holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and the second one is locally isomorphic to zero locus of some holomorphic functions on some open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are not necessarily biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$, I think the two definitions may be distinct, but why they are both called complex analytic spaces? Or are they just the same but I did not notice that?
Thanks in advance.

I'd be really surprised if the definition from the nLab holds verbatim. Also, their reference introductory text (the link is broken, but I guess it is Appendix A of this one) doesn't seem to contain this definition...
